# Using data movement sdk ,want to remove collection from docs in real time in marklogic?

Tags: sdk, marklogic

Actually I am new to data movement SDK,I want to know how we can used data movement sdk to remove collection from docs which match's specific condition in real time in marklogic ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, DMSK can reprocess documents in the database including modifying the collections on the documents.

The  most efficient way to change document collections on the server might be to take an approach similar to the out-of-the-box ApplyTransformListener (as summarized by
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/data-movement#id_51555) but to execute a custom module instead of a transform.

Summarizing the main points:

1. Write an SJS (Server-Side JavaScript) module that declares a variable (using the JavaScript `var` statement) to receive the document URIs sent by the client and modifies the collections on those documents using a function such as
   https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.documentSetCollections
2. Install the SJS module in the modules database as described here
   https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_13008
3. Create a `QueryBatcher` to get the document URIs either from a query on the database or from a client iterator as described here:
   https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/data-movement#id_46947
4. Supply a lambda function for the `QueryBatcher.onUrisReady()` method - see
   https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/datamovement/QueryBatcher.html#onUrisReady-com.marklogic.client.datamovement.QueryBatchListener-
5. In the lambda function, construct and execute a ServerEvaluationCall to the SJS module, assigning the variable to the URIs passed to the lambda function - see:
   https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_84134
6. Be sure to register failure listeners using the `QueryBatcher.onQueryFailure()` `ApplyTransformListener.onFailure​()` methods to log error or otherwise respond to the unexpected.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Is this a one time process or it will  repeat the entire process in specific interval of time, If not,how can we do this?

Comment: DMSDK QueryBatcher executes a job, matching and processing documents while the job is running.  If you need to run the job regularly, use a scheduler to kick off the job.  On a Linux system, the chron job can execute a Java application that runs the QueryBatcher job.